# Facebook Gameroom assetbundle

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

We are using Unity 5.6.

In our Unity game we have asset bundles. While porting the game to Facebook Gameroom, we wanted to handle asset bundle.

Currently we are not able to find the build target as GameRoom while creating the asset bundle.

Is it possible to create asset bundle for Gameroom? IF yes then what is the build target we need to select during creation of the asset bundle.